# How do I install a virtual mouse to enable scroll wheel on a Synergy client?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, scrolling, synergy, gaming

Hmm, I fear I was unable to sum up the question clearly in the title. Here's what's going on.... I have a 3 computer setup and use synergy. My primary machine controls wake on Lan, Synergy and other server functions for my mini network. The 3rd machine is my gaming rig. The mouse scroll wheel will not work with some games (i.e. Killing Floor, Dungeon Defenders) unless the mouse is physically attached to the machine.

The scroll wheel does work with other applications and games on all machines, so I'm assuming something within the affected games looks for an attached device before binding the mouse wheel. Why only the wheel is affected, I have no idea. I can plug the mouse into Comp 3, start the game, and reattach it to the Comp 1 and the wheel will work with the games over the network. Not that I want to do this every time, but this seems to suggest that the game engine is responsible.

So my workaround for this is to add a virtual device (mouse) so that the game will utilize the scroll wheel functions. How can I accomplish this? Is there another way to force bindings for a device that is not actually attached to the machine?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shameless bump (heehee)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, most likely caused by an incompatibility between Synergy and the game's API. Do you happen to know whether you're using DirectX or OpenGL? You could [raise a bug](https://github.com/synergy/synergy/issues/new) if you like.